# Solving a non-linear system of equations in Matrix form in Python

Tags: python, matrix, equations, nonlinear-functions

I am trying to solve a non-linear system of equations of the form AX=X where,

A = M-by-M matrix

X = M-by-1 matrix

Thus, in total I have M (=200) equations (and M unknowns).

More specifically,

A = [f11(x,y) f12(x,y) .... f1m(x,y),

```
 f21(x,y) f22(x,y) .....f2m(x,y),

 ..        ..           ..

 fm1(x,y) fm2(x,y) .... fmm(x,y)]
```

X = [V1,

```
   V2,

   V3,
   .
   .
   Vm-2,
   0.33,
   0.33]
```

Thus, X has M-2 unknown (V1, V2 ... Vm-1) and A has two (x and y). The elements of A are LINEAR functions of x and y.

I did my homework on scipy.fsolve and sympy.nsolve but they dont seem to accept the equations in the matrix format. Also, since there are 200 equations and each equations would have all the unknown, its impractical to eliminate variables one-by-one.

I am relatively new to python so any help is greatly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: yes, they are real numbers and so is x and y. The linear function fij also maps to real. example, fij = 0.21 - x- y

Answer (score 1):

Let f<sub>ij</sub>(x,y) = a<sub>i</sub>x + b<sub>j</sub>y. Let a = (a<sub>1</sub>, ..., a<sub>m</sub>), b = (b<sub>1</sub>, ..., b<sub>m</sub>), and v = (V<sub>1</sub>, ... V<sub>m-2</sub>, 1/3, 1/3) be real column vectors. Then

A = [f<sub>ij</sub>(x,y)]<sub>m×m</sub>
  = [a<sub>i</sub>x + b<sub>j</sub>y]<sub>m×m</sub>
  = [a<sub>i</sub>x]<sub>m×1</sub>[b<sub>j</sub>y]<sub>1×m</sub>
  = ([a<sub>i</sub>]<sub>m×1</sub>x)([b<sub>j</sub>]<sub>1×m</sub>y)

Your equation is Av = v, or Av = Iv (where I is the m×m identity matrix), so you want to solve (A-I)v = 0. This is reminiscent of an eigenvalue problem. The [characteristic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Characteristic_equation) for that eigenvalue problem is 0 = det(A-I) = det(([a<sub>i</sub>]<sub>m×1</sub>x)([b<sub>j</sub>]<sub>1×m</sub>y) - I), where det is the determinant (I fixed the eigenvalue at 1).

A possible approach would be to numerically solve det(([a<sub>i</sub>]<sub>m×1</sub>x)([b<sub>j</sub>]<sub>1×m</sub>y) - I) = 0 for x and y (using a root-finding algorithm like [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)), yielding a constant matrix A.

Next, go back and use a linear equation solver to solve (A-I)v = 0 to find v<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>2</sub>, ..., v<sub>m-2</sub> using your constant matrix A that you solved for numerically. Unfortunately, this won't preserve your 1/3 constants at the bottom of v, so you'll have to go back and redo the previous step a few times until you get a matrix A that approximates 1/3 for the last two values.

---

An alternative solution would be to just stick the whole thing in a nonlinear equation solver. This approach will be slower than the one I explained above.

Comment: Thank for your response. Thinking of this problem as eigenvalue problem is certainly one way to do it.

However, as far as plugging this in a nonlinear equation solver goes (ex. fsolve or nsolve), it is my understanding that It still requires me to rewrite my equations in AX=B format, where A has all the knowns and X has all the unknowns, which is not so straightforward for 200 equations. 

am I mistaken?

Comment: @user1618128: You're not mistaken, it would just be a system of 200 equations. The part above the horizontal line is probably the better approach of the two (though I haven't tried it, so it might not work at all).